# Accessing Current SharedPreferences Data from Background Services

Tags: android-studio, sharedpreferences

My app uses a countdown timer in the background in a class that extends Services. The background running service is designed to access the `Sharedpreferences` data of the app. During the countdown, a particular integer in the `Sharedpreferences` changes value and the updated value is expected to be accessed in the `onFinish()` call of the countdown timer. The problem now is that the Service don't read the updated valued from the `Sharedpreference`s but rather returns the initial value at the point the background service started.

I saw somewhere that the solution to the problem is to use

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()
```

instead of `getSharedPrefences` to be able access the current `SharedPreferences` value. I implemented this recommendation but the problem persist.

Please somebody should help me out because trying to figure out this is taking too much of my time.

My code is here:

```
public class BroadcastService extends Service {

DatabaseHelperClass myDatabase = new DatabaseHelperClass(this);

private SharedPreferences defaultSharedPreferences, sharedPreferences, staffSignedIn;
private SharedPreferences.Editor staffEditor, defaultSharedPreferencesEditor;
int countSignIn;

private SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatII;

Long timeLeftInMiliseconds;

private final static String TAG = "BroadcastService";

public static final String COUNTDOWN_BR = "com.cenitscitech.www.etimebook.countdown_br";
Intent bi = new Intent(COUNTDOWN_BR);

CountDownTimer cdt = null;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    defaultSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    defaultSharedPreferencesEditor = defaultSharedPreferences.edit();
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("setTime", MODE_PRIVATE);
    //staffSignedIn = getSharedPreferences("present", MODE_PRIVATE);

    //countSignIn = staffSignedIn.getInt("max", 0);

    //staffEditor = staffSignedIn.edit();
    simpleDateFormatII = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM EEE dd, yyyy HH:mm");

    Log.i(TAG, "Starting timer in broadcast receiver...");
    Log.i(TAG, "max Count Obtained onBroadcastCreate: "+defaultSharedPreferences.getInt("max", 0));

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    //cdt.cancel();
    Log.i(TAG, "Timer in broadcast receiver cancelled");
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    timeLeftInMiliseconds = intent.getLongExtra("timeLeft", 0L);

    cdt = new CountDownTimer(timeLeftInMiliseconds, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            SharedPreferences defaultShared = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

            Log.i(TAG, "Countdown seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            /*bi.putExtra("countdown", millisUntilFinished);
            sendBroadcast(bi);*/
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            SharedPreferences defaultSharedPreferences2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            countSignIn = defaultSharedPreferences2.getInt("max", 0);
            Log.i(TAG, "Timer finished");
            bi.putExtra("countdown", "Timer finished");
            sendBroadcast(bi);

            StringBuilder phoneBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            Calendar cStart = Calendar.getInstance();
            cStart.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
            cStart.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            cStart.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            Long cStartLong = cStart.getTimeInMillis();

            Calendar cEnd = Calendar.getInstance();
            cEnd.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
            cEnd.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
            cEnd.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
            Long cEndLong = cEnd.getTimeInMillis();

            String[] conditionsElements;

            Log.i(TAG + " onFinish", "MAXIMUM COUNT OBTAINED: " + defaultSharedPreferences2.getInt("max", 0));
            Log.i(TAG + " onFinish", "MAXIMUM COUNT OBTAINED: " + countSignIn);

            if (defaultSharedPreferences2.getInt("max", 0) > 0) {
                Log.i(TAG + " onFinish", "CURRENT countSignIn Value: "+countSignIn+"\n"+" max Value: "+defaultSharedPreferences2.getInt("max", 0));
                conditionsElements = new String[defaultSharedPreferences2.getInt("max", 0)];
                for (int i = 1; i <= defaultSharedPreferences2.getInt("max", 0); i++) {
                    conditionsElements[i - 1] = defaultSharedPreferences2.getString(Integer.toString(i), "NoElement");
                    Log.i(TAG + " onFinish", "conditionsElement[" + (i - 1) + "] = " + defaultSharedPreferences2.getString(Integer.toString(i), "NoElement"));
                    if (i < defaultSharedPreferences2.getInt("max", 0)) {
                        phoneBuilder.append("MOBILE_NUMBER = ? OR ");
                        Log.i(TAG + " onFinish", "phoneBuilder[" + (i - 1) + "]: " + phoneBuilder);
                        //phoneBuilder.append(staffSignedIn.getString(Integer.toString(i), "NoStaff")+"_");
                    } else if (i == defaultSharedPreferences2.getInt("max", 0)) {
                        //phoneBuilder.append(staffSignedIn.getString(Integer.toString(i), "NoStaff"));
                        phoneBuilder.append("MOBILE_NUMBER = ?");
                        Log.i(TAG + " onFinish", "phoneBuilder[final]: " + phoneBuilder);
                    }
                }

            } else {
                Log.i(TAG + " onFinishInsideElse", "CURRENT countSignIn Value: "+countSignIn+"\n"+" max Value: "+defaultSharedPreferences2.getInt("max", 0));
                conditionsElements = new String[1];
                conditionsElements[0] = "NoElement";
                phoneBuilder.append("MOBILE_NUMBER = ?");
            }

            Cursor cursor = myDatabase.queryAbsentStaff(SURNAME_COLUMN + ", " + FIRST_NAME_COLUMN + ", " + MIDDLE_NAME_COLUMN + ", " + MOBILE_NUMBER_COLUMN + ", " + DATE_COLUMN,
                    SURNAME_COLUMN + ", " + FIRST_NAME_COLUMN + ", " + MIDDLE_NAME_COLUMN + ", " + MOBILE_NUMBER_COLUMN + ", " + DATE_COLUMN,
                    phoneBuilder.toString(),
                    conditionsElements);


            Log.i(TAG + " onFinish", "\n" + "SET TIMES:" + "\n" + cStartLong + "\n" + cEndLong + "\n" + "RETURNED ROWS:" + "\n" + cursor.getCount());
            /*staffEditor.putInt("max", 0);
            staffEditor.apply();
            for(int i=0; i<staffSignedIn.getInt("totalStaff", 100); i++){
                staffEditor.putString(Integer.toString((i+1)), "empty").apply();
            }*/
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {

                    if(myDatabase.insertTimeBookRecord(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SURNAME_COLUMN)), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FIRST_NAME_COLUMN)),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MIDDLE_NAME_COLUMN)), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MOBILE_NUMBER_COLUMN)),
                            "ABSENT", Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()), 1000000L, "NO", "0000", System.currentTimeMillis(), "notSynced", "notSynced")){
                        cursor.moveToNext();
                        if(cursor.isAfterLast()){
                            cursor.close();
                        }
                    }else{
                        cursor.moveToNext();
                        if(cursor.isAfterLast()){
                            cursor.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Log.i(TAG +" onFinish: ", "max val reset: "+defaultSharedPreferences2.getInt("max", 0));
```

Comment: "During the countdown, a particular integer in the `Sharedpreferences` changes value..." – I don't see where you're updating any `SharedPreferences` value during the countdown.

Comment: @MikeM.The "max" integer changes value from user interaction with one of the activity classes not directly in the `BroadcastService`  class.

Comment: Hmm, OK, I'm not sure if I'm correctly following the entire flow, but do you happen to be running your `BroadcastService` in a separate process? That is, do you have an `android:process` attribute on its `<service>` element in the manifest?

Comment: @MikeM. Yes sure. Specifically this: `android:process=":ServiceProcess"`

Comment: Yeah, that's at least part of your problem. `SharedPreferences` don't really work across processes. Remove that, and give it another test.

Comment: Yes, it is now working fine! Thank you so much @MikeM.

Comment: No problem. I should mention, though, that if you really do need that `Service` running in a separate process, for some reason, there are other solutions – not involving `SharedPreferences` – but that's usually not a necessity for most apps. Anyhoo, glad you got it working. Cheers!